# proc.communiate() is not waiting for svn command to finish

Tags: python, svn

This python code:

```
print "Start update"
print " ".join(["svn","update",workspace_root)
proc = subprocess.Popen(["svn","update",workspace_root])
proc.communicate()
if (proc.returncode!= 0):
    do_exit("Error trying to update "+workspace_root)
print "Finish update"
```

# CD into the workspace

Delivers this result:

```
Start update
svn update /data/home/vuser13/verify_and_merge_repo 
Finish update
Updating 'verify_and_merge_repo':
At revision 307.
```

Notice that the proc.communicate() is not waiting until the `svn` command completes.

What's up?  My cron job is overrunning itself on long operations because it is not waiting for this to complete.  I see the same behavior with `subprocess.call()`.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `proc.wait()`?

Comment: Which operating system? This kind of thing can happend on Windows with batch files ('cron' is a hint of course, but checking anyway).

Comment: I'm running on Red Hat 6. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should give the `stdout=PIPE` argument to `Popen` so you root process waits for child process to return something.

Read more here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate especially this bit:

> Similarly, to get anything other than None in the result tuple, you need to give stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE too.

Comment: `communicate` and `call` both call `wait` before completing. You don't need to redirect `stdout` to use them.

Comment: TIL. Thanks a lot! tdelaney

Comment: And again TIL :D. Good to know.